# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1, 1])) - BCEWithLogitsLoss

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I read about the above mentioned error but could not find a solution in my case.

So probably the question would be how do I change my target to torch.Size([1,1])?

(I had to cut out some code parts for posting it here)

densenet:

```
class DenseNet(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=1e-4):
        super().__init__()
        self.densenet = densenet.densenet121(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1, out_channels=1)
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.class_loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='mean') #binarycorssentropy loss bceloss

    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.densenet(x)
        return logits


   
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        mri, y  = batch['mri'], batch['label']
        logits = self(mri)
        y_hat = (logits >= 0).float()
        class_loss = self.class_loss(logits, y)
        self.log('loss/train', class_loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.train_predictions.extend(y_hat.tolist())
        self.train_labels.extend(y.tolist())
        return class_loss

    def on_validation_epoch_start(self):
        self.predictions = []
        self.labels = []

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        mri, y = batch['mri'], batch['label']
        logits = self(mri)
        y_hat = (logits >= 0).float()
        class_loss = self.class_loss(logits, y)
        self.log(f'loss/valid', class_loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.predictions.extend(y_hat.tolist())
        self.labels.extend(y.tolist())

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        cm = pycm.ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=self.labels, predict_vector=self.predictions)
        self.log('accuracy/valid', cm.Overall_ACC)
        if cm.F1_Macro is not 'None':
            self.log('f1_macro/valid', cm.F1_Macro)
        if cm.F1_Micro is not 'None':
            self.log('f1_micro/valid', cm.F1_Micro)
```

Comment: `class_loss = self.class_loss(logits, y.unsqueeze(0))`

Comment: Great that works. But now it throws me: File "/Users/Wu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2982, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
    return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

RuntimeError: result type Float can't be cast to the desired output type Long

Comment: Okay, that works now.